# Как сократить url для определенного типа постов в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Можно ли для определенного типа постов сократить url, убрать из него названия типа постов.
Т.е. есть у меня условно говоря тип news в нем запись "news-1" следовательно url должен быть site.ru/news-1
При этом другие типы постов оставались в нормальном состоянии т.е. site.ru/post_type/post

В какую сторону хотя бы копать?

Comment: Смотреть на register_post_type() -> rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $post_link, $post ) {
  if ( 'news' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
     $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
  }

 return $post_link;
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) || 2 !== count( $query->query ) ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'post', 'page', 'news' ] );
} );
```

И в случае если slug вашего пост тайпа отличается от его названия, в том смысле что у вас пост тайп `customers`, но slug для него `customer`, в `str_replace` подставьте `slug`.

Comment: не запустилось что-то, сделал по другому. по совету @SeVlad изменил параметр при регистрации нового типа поста `'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/','with_front' => false),`

Comment: не, мой способ не сработал, отвалились статичные страницы. Ваш метод, выдает 404 на целевых как раз страницах

Comment: Вы там больше ничего не меняли? На чистой установке на теме TwentyTwenty с добавлением одного post type у меня работает.

Comment: не, вот прям взял и вставил

Comment: А что у вас в register_post_type? Можете скриншот приатачить?

Comment: скнин создания нового типа, а вообще создаю через плагин Custom Post Type UI [скрин](https://ibb.co/2c8C3gP)

Comment: @Алексей повторил все ваши шаги на чистой установке, у меня работает, смотрите [видео](https://scrstorage.s3.amazonaws.com/cw8l02020-11-12_17-38-44.mp4) возможно вы забыли что-то заменить или какой-то другой ваш код конфликтует, либо какой-то плагин.

Comment: Решил плагином Remove CPT base, все остальное что пробовал и находил в сети, или ломает текущие записи или ломает другие страницы